# Can you create a second <body> on a html page? (Website in website)

Tags: html, document-body

Ok, my title may sound confusing, but I don't know a better summarized way to describe it. (feel free to change).

The thing is: I've built a wayfinder for school, as a school project. I want to use it for my portfolio. But the wayfinder is built on the size of your whole screen, but I want something like a website in a website.

Let's say it like this.

```
prototyping.iscs.nl
```

That's my wayfinder.
I want something like a area of H 800 x W 480 that is a whole new piece of html, that where I can place HTML in, which would result in some kind of 'a website within a website'.

Since my wayfinder is built based on the CSS of

```
html, body { width:100% height:100% }
```

I doubt if you can just create this with a parent div.

For an visual example of what I want to achieve:

[image: My wayfinder]

And yes: The wayfinder should be interactive, like the normal webpage.

Comment: This is what frames are created for. Have a look at how www.jsfiddle.net does it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have a look at iframes ,if that's what you're looking for:

```
<iframe src="your-url" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```